# How do you count the number of Opportunities associated with a Contact?

Tags: salesforce

I am unable to figure out how to create a roll-up field which will count active Opportunities on a Contact. It is easy to get a count at the Account level, however that's for all Opportunities associated with an Account, which may or may not be related to the specific Contact I'm looking at.

Is there a way to query the Contact / Opportunity relationship and return a count?

Answer (score 2):

Do you use the standard many-to-many relationship? [OpportunityContactRole](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_opportunitycontactrole.htm) object acts as junction between the two (many Contacts can be involved in many Opportunities).

Or have you created some custom lookup to Contact on Opp (I've seen organisations that cared about only 1 guy, called it "Primary Contact" for example).

[image]

(full image is at http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_erd_majors.htm; or use Setup -> Schema builder in your organisation)

You could go with straightforward `SELECT COUNT() FROM OpportunityContactRole WHERE ContactId = '...'` but if there's an Opportunity that lists one guy more than once - it'll be double counted it.

So this is bit better:

```
SELECT Id, Name
FROM Opportunity
WHERE Id IN (SELECT OpportunityId 
    FROM OpportunityContactRole 
    WHERE ContactId = '0037000000TWREI')
```

Of course it's just a stub, once you have it you can play around (use `COUNT(Id)`, `WHERE Contact.Email = 'joe@example.com'` or put extra `AND Status = 'Closed Won'`)...

Comment: Thank you eyescream. I'm not 100% sure yet that this will fix my issue, but I very much appreciate the help.

Comment: Good luck :) Feel free editing the question if you'll run into some issues. Or you can also try posting on salesforce.stackexchange.com, maybe more people needed similar thing (there seem to be more Salesforce admins over there whereas StackOverflow is mostly for programmers).